# Python cx_Oracle and csv extracts saved differently with different executions

Tags: python, csv, cx-oracle

I'm working on a Python Script that runs queries against an Oracle Database and saves the results to csv. The greater plan is to use regular extracts with a separate application to check differences in the files through hashing.

The issue I've run into is that my script has so far saved some fields in the extracts in different formats. For example, saving a field as an integer in one extract and as a float in the next, and saving a date at 2000/01/01 in one and 2000-01-01 in another.

These changes are giving my difference check script a fit. What can I do to ensure that every extract is saved the same way, while keeping the script generic enough to run arbitrary queries?

```
import sys
import traceback
import cx_Oracle
from Creds import creds
import csv
import argparse
import datetime

try:
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(
        '{username}/{password}@{address}/{dbname}'.format(**creds)
        )
except cx_Oracle.Error as e:
    print('Unable to connect to database.')
    print()
    print(''.join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())), file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)


def run_extract(query, out):
    """
    Run the given query and save results to given out path.

    :param query: Query to be executed.
    :param out: Path to store results in csv.
    """

    cur = conn.cursor()

    try:
        cur.execute(query)
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        print('Unable to run given query.')
        print()
        print(query)
        print()
        print(''.join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())), file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)

    with open(out, 'w', newline='') as out_file:
        wrt = csv.writer(out_file)

        header = []

        for column in cur.description:
            header.append(column[0])

        wrt.writerow(header)

        for row in cur:
            wrt.writerow(row)

    cur.close()


def read_sql(file_path):
    """
    Read the SQL from a given filepath and return as a string.

    :param file_path: File path location of the file to read.
    """

    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            return file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print('File not found a given path.')
        print()
        print(file_path)
        print()
        print(''.join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())), file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)


def generate_timestamp_path(path):
    """
    Add a timestamp to the beginning of the given path.

    :param path: File path for the timestamp to be added to.
    """

    if '/' in args.out_file:
        sep = '/'
    elif '\\' in args.out_file:
        sep = '\\'
    else:
        sep = ''

    path = args.out_file.split(sep)
    stamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%S ')
    path[-1] = stamp + path[-1]

    return sep.join(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    in_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    in_group.add_argument('-q', '--query', help='String of the query to run.')
    in_group.add_argument('-f', '--in_file', help='File of the query to run.')

    parser.add_argument('-o', '--out_file', help='Path to file to store.')

    parser.add_argument('-t', '--timestamp',
                        help='Store the file with a preceding timestamp.',
                        action='store_true')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args.out_file:
        print('Please provide a path to put the query results with -o.')
        sys.exit(1)

    if args.timestamp:
        path = generate_timestamp_path(args.out_file)
    else:
        path = args.out_file

    if args.query:
        query = args.query
    elif args.in_file:
        query = read_sql(args.in_file)
    else:
        print('Please provide either a query string with -q',
              'or a SQL file with -f.')
        sys.exit(1)

    run_extract(query, path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is simply using the default transformations for all data types. Note that an Oracle type of number(9) will be returned as an integer but number by itself will be returned as a float. You may wish to use an outputtypehandler in order to place this under your control a bit more firmly. :-) Examples for doing so are in the cx_Oracle distribution samples directory (ReturnLongs and ReturnUnicode). All of that said, though, the same data definition in Oracle will always return the same type in Python -- so I would suspect that you are referencing different data types in Oracle that you would prefer to see processed the same way.

Comment: In my processing for that time, the script literally ran the same query 8 seconds apart from one another. I will look up the outputtypehandlers. :-)

Comment: Hmm, curious! I'd love to have a test case that demonstrates this behaviour. If you have one, please let me know! Thanks.